# Seaborn python does not show the axes and strips correctly

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization

I am trying to visualize kaggle/titanic data in seaborn. But it does not show the vertical axis label and numbers. Also the strip/bar size is not presetting the counted numbers (All strips have the same size and with very narrow width)

code:

```
sns.catplot('Sex',data=titanic)
```

what I get:
[image: catplot visualization of gender in titanic data, missed axis, narrow strips]

What I expect (based on what I see in coursera class content):

[image: the image I expect to see]

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the parameter `kind` in the `sns.catplot` method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
sns.catplot("sex", data=titanic[titanic.deck.notnull()], kind="count", height=5, aspect=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please consider [accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so other people with the same question know too :)